# Maintaining a map of which keys are down in the presence of Undo, Copy, etc

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm building a web application with a fullscreen canvas that needs to react to continuous and discrete keyboard input.
My current approach is similar to the one in this question: [JavaScript keep track of which keys are down accurately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023968/javascript-keep-track-of-which-keys-are-down-accurately).

I maintain a set of which keys are currently pressed using `keyEvent.code` to differentiate keys. I query this set in the `requestAnimationFrame` loop of my application. I update the set in event handlers for the `'keyup'` and `'keydown'` events attached to `window`.

## The Problem

When pressing and releasing Cmd+Z to undo, the `'keydown'` event fires but the `'keyup'` event does not (at least in the latest Firefox, Chrome, and Edge on macOS 10.15.6).
Consequently, my set contains an entry for `'KeyZ'` even though the Z key on the keyboard is not being held. Similarly, Cmd+C, Cmd+V, and many other system shortcuts seem to hijack the `'keyup'` event.

Why am I not getting a `'keyup'` event in this case? What can I do to ensure that my set accurately reflects the state of the currently held keys on the keyboard?

## What I've Tried

This seems like it could be related to event propagation, so I tried using `keyEvent.stopPropagation()` and `keyEvent.preventDefault()` in the `keydown` event handler.
I've tried pressing Control+Z instead, which does fire a `'keyup'` event.

## Problem Reproduction

```js
const listenerTarget = window;
const useCapture = false;
const heldKeys = new Set();

listenerTarget.addEventListener('keydown', (keyEvent) => {
  const code = keyEvent.code;
  if (!keyEvent.repeat) {
    console.log(`${code} went down`);
    heldKeys.add(code);
  } else {
    console.log(`${code} went down (repeat)`);
  }
  keyEvent.stopPropagation();
  keyEvent.preventDefault();
}, useCapture);

listenerTarget.addEventListener('keyup', (keyEvent) => {
  const code = keyEvent.code;
  // Why does this not fire if
  // the 'keydown' happened in combination with
  // a Meta key?
  console.log(`${code} went up`);
  heldKeys.delete(code);
}, useCapture);
```

## Workaround Update (11/03/2020)

I found [When CMD key is kept pressed, keyup is not triggered for any other key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380018/when-cmd-key-is-kept-pressed-keyup-is-not-triggered-for-any-other-key?rq=1) and http://web.archive.org/web/20160304022453/http://bitspushedaround.com/on-a-few-things-you-may-not-know-about-the-hellish-command-key-and-javascript-events/, which indicate that this is known behavior. My current workaround is to not add codes to the set of held keys if `keyEvent.metaKey` is set. Doing this at least ensures that the set of held keys doesn't contain phantom entries. I'll keep this question open in case someone can think of a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

[image: works]

For me it works just fine on the lates chrome version..
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't *super* helpful, but there's a bunch of good info here: https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.  You've probably already seen that in other answers though.

I say not super helpful because it doesn't really answer your particular question, but it does show that there's definite weirdness between browser versions and both modifier keys and branded keys.  I suspect the answer is that the branded keys like the windows key and cmd key just act weird because they tend to trigger system level events.  I would just use different keys, but hopefully someone else will know a way around this other than "use different keys".

For windows people, you can produce really similar results by doing Windows Key + Z.  You'll only get up event for Z and no down events.